# Cannot connect my windows 8.1 OS machine remotely

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-8.1, mstsc

I have newly installed windows 8.1 OS desktop PC.

In my PC, I can't see the "Remote Desktop" option in "Remote Tab" in the System properties window.

[image]

So I cannot connect to remotely my machine from other machine using **mstsc** command.

I have tried the below steps:

1. disable fire walls.
2. Selected "Allow Remote assistance connection to
   this computer option in system properties    window.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This belongs on superuser.com

Comment: @PraveenVR For those in the future reading this question who'd like to know the reason why - because the above user has the *Non-Pro* version of Windows 8.1. I found this out the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

well this is what I do. I go to search I type 'remote' and I get the Remote Desktop Connection window. This has not been changed on windows 8.1. http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Remote-Desktop-on-Windows-8. check this link. if this doesn't work try to check if remote desktop has been turned on from 'Windows Features'

Comment: these steps are already done.but still have the problem

Comment: hmm..looks like there is a bug in ur OS installation.